# How can I plot the change of data from a higher timeframe?

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to plot the "future pivot" on a chart. I have the code that I'm using below.

```
lstyle     = input(title = "Line Style", options = ['Solid', 'Circles', 'Cross'], defval ='Solid')


linestyle = lstyle == 'Solid' ? plot.style_line :   lstyle == 'Circles' ? plot.style_circles : plot.style_cross



getData(t) =>
    highhtf = security(syminfo.tickerid, t, high,  lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
    lowhtf = security(syminfo.tickerid, t, low, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
    closehtf = security(syminfo.tickerid, t, close, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

    (highhtf + lowhtf + closehtf) / 3.0
    

dP = getData("D")
wP = getData("W")
mP = getData("M")
yP = getData("12M")
    
//D
plot(dP, title = "Tomorrow Pivot", color =  dP !=dP[1] ? na : color.fuchsia, linewidth = 1, style = linestyle, trackprice = true)
```

This just draws a straight line. As the line changes it does plot differently. But when looking at historic data the line is just straight. At the beginning and end of a time period (like a day) the lines do change.

[image]

As price changes throughout the time period, the data I'm sure changes also. Is there a way to plot the change from the beginning of the time period (let's say a day) until now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yellow line shows the change throughout the day.
I also simplified your `getData()` function.

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay=true)

lstyle     = input(title = "Line Style", options = ['Solid', 'Circles', 'Cross'], defval ='Solid')
linestyle = lstyle == 'Solid' ? plot.style_line : lstyle == 'Circles' ? plot.style_circles : plot.style_cross

var float dh = na
var float dl = na
var float pChange = na

getData(t) => security(syminfo.tickerid, t, hlc3 , lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

dP = getData("D")
wP = getData("W")
mP = getData("M")
yP = getData("12M")

if change(time('D'))
    dh := high
    dl := low
else
    dh := max(dh,high)
    dl := min(dl,low)

pChange := avg(dh, dl, close)

//D
plot(dP, title = "Tomorrow Pivot", color = change(dP) ? na : color.fuchsia, linewidth = 1, style = linestyle, trackprice = true)
plot(pChange, color = color.yellow, style=plot.style_stepline)
```

Which yields this

[image: Example]

Edit 1 in response to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68025206/how-can-i-plot-the-change-of-data-from-a-higher-timeframe/68031374?noredirect=1#comment120274980_68031374)

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay=true)

lstyle     = input(title = "Line Style", options = ['Solid', 'Circles', 'Cross'], defval ='Solid')
linestyle = lstyle == 'Solid' ? plot.style_line : lstyle == 'Circles' ? plot.style_circles : plot.style_cross

var float dh = na
var float dl = na
var float pChange = na

getData(t) => security(syminfo.tickerid, t, hlc3 , lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

dP = getData("D")
wP = getData("W")
mP = getData("M")
yP = getData("12M")

if session.ismarket
    if change(time('D'))
        dh := high
        dl := low
    else
        dh := max(dh,high)
        dl := min(dl,low)
    
    pChange := avg(dh, dl, close)
else
    dh := na
    dl := na
    pChange := na


//D
plot(dP, title = "Tomorrow Pivot", color = change(dP) or na(pChange) ? na : color.fuchsia, linewidth = 1, style = linestyle, trackprice = true)
plot(pChange, color = pChange ? color.blue : na, style=plot.style_stepline)
```

Which yields

[image: Example]

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm getting a different chart that looks like this when I copy and paste your code: https://pasteboard.co/K7bir68.png I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I changed the yellow line to blue to show up on my white background chart.

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong. It's just that you have extended hours enabled on your chart. `security()` calls don't take extended hours into account, so the `getData("D")` call will not take those extended hours into account. If you disable extended hours, it will work.

Comment: Okay got it. Thanks so much. Last question, is there a way to overcome this without having to turn off extended hours? Or is this a limitation I can't get around?

Comment: I don't think there's a way around it, because `security()` calls cannot be made to take extended hours into account afaik.

Comment: I appreciate your responsiveness. You’ve done an amazing job. One more question. Can I do the reverse? Can I have it plot without extended hours without having to change the settings on the chart? This way it performs as it should.

Comment: Added Edit 1 section to my answer. Is this what you mean?